# Cron task / Grab data (Curl?) Insert into form and submit it

Tags: php, curl, cron

I'm trying to retrieve data from an external website, that website has 1 line of text / URL that changes every 5 minutes. Now I want to take this URL and submit a form (every 5 minutes) with this URL and store it into my DB(Cron job on php file?) alternatively insert it directly into my mysql DB.

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to acquire 2 tasks:

1) Getting URL from external page and storing it in your DB

2) Executing above every 5 minutes.

Here they are:

1) CURL is a good way, should be available on all servers. You may also try file_get_contents it it's not restricted on your server. Curl function looks like this:

```
<?php
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
    {
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        $contents = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);

        if ($contents) return $contents;
            else return FALSE;
    }
?>
```

This function returns string with page content. Probably you need to extract your URL from there, use PHPs SUBSTR if URL has constant length, or STRPOS. When you get your URL, store it in DB - there's no need to use form.

2) The simplest way to execute script every 5 minutes is using javascript. It would go like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(300000);">
<?php // your code here
```

This page will refresh every 5 minutes (300 thousand miliseconds) and will execute PHP script each time - but you have to have it constantly opened in browser. It that's a problem, use CRON (I hardly used it, so no help here from me).